# Highcharts Unable to set value of the property 'point': object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using high charts to construct stacked bar chart. I am able to construct it using mock data, but when pass object it throes me Unable to set value of the property 'point': object is null or undefined error.

Here is my code

```
var data.series1 = [{//some properties, y:21}];
var data.series2 = [{//some properties, y:21}];
var data.series3 = [{//some properties, y:21}];
var data.series4 = [{//some properties, y:21}];
var data.colors ={// color values};
chart(data);
```

Here is my chart configuration

```
var setConfig = function (data) {
//chart options
  series: [{
            name: 'avalPoints',
            data:data.series1 ,
            color: data.colors.avail
        }, {
            name: 'Q4',
            data: data.series2 ,
            color: data.colors.q4
        }, {
            name: 'Q3',
            data: data.series3,
            color: data.colors.q3
        }, {
            name: 'Q2',
            data: data.series4,             
            color: data.colors.q2
        }
}
```

When use static values  like below

```
   {
            name: 'Q2',
            data: [21],             
            color: data.colors.q2
        }
```

it is working. Can anybody point where I am doing mistake please?

Comment: Provide a JSFiddle example which reproduces the error. I can't see anything wrong from the code you provide.

Comment: I could have posted a fiddle but have security issues. But thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you already have a var data already defined, so it seems that you have bad syntax.

```
var data.series1 = [/*  */];
```

Should not work. Try:

```
data.series1 = [/*  */];
```

Comment: That isn't the issue, but thank you for your time and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. I have a property called dataLabel in data.series object. That is causing issue. After renaming it, charts are constructed.